# How can I check if a string (is not) exist in an array?

Tags: javascript

```
var colors = ["blue", "cyan", "gold", "grey", "orange", "red"];
var gussess = 0;
var color_choosed;
var color_guessed;

function game() {
    color_choosed = "grey";
    color_guessed = prompt("I'm thinking of one of these colors");
    if (colors.indexOf(color_guessed) > colors.indexOf(color_choosed))
        alert("The color choosed is after my color");
    else if (colors.indexOf(color_guessed) < colors.indexOf(color_choosed))
        alert("The coloris befor my color");
    else if (colors.indexOf(color_guessed) == colors.indexOf(color_choosed))
        alert("congrats you are right my color is " + color_guessed);
    else if (color_guessed not in colors)
        alert("The color is not in the list");
}
```

I want to write an `if` statement to check if the user has put a color not in the list .. do something ? to give him an alert that the color is not in the list

Comment: `colors.indexOf(input) === -1`

Comment: else if ( colors.indexOf(color_guessed) === -1 )
    alert("The color is is not in the list");
dosn't work with me also

Comment: Because of this I guess: `if (colors.indexOf(color_guessed) < colors.indexOf(color_choosed))`. Here it should be like `-1 < 3`

Comment: There is also the more semantic [*includes*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.includes): `if (colors.includes(color_guessed)) ...`. Might not be available in some browsers though, and has slightly different behaviour (which might be preferred).

Answer (score 3):

> I want to write an if statement to check if the user has put a color not in the list ..

Here is the *if* statement you can use to check if the user's input is in your array:

```
if(colors.indexOf(color_guessed) === -1) { // code here }
```

**Important notice**: *[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)* returns `-1` if the value is not present in the array. This will make some additional side effect in your code.
In order to fix this, you shall move your last *if* statement to the beginning, making it the first one, like so:

```
function game() {
    color_choosed = "grey";
    color_guessed = prompt("I'm thinking of one of these colors");
    if(colors.indexOf(color_guessed) === -1) // color not found in array
        alert("The color is not in the list");
    else if (colors.indexOf(color_guessed) > colors.indexOf(color_choosed)) // color is after
        alert("The color choosed is after my color");
    else if (colors.indexOf(color_guessed) < colors.indexOf(color_choosed)) // color is before
        alert("The coloris befor my color");
    else if (color_guessed === color_choosed) // colors match!
        alert("congrats you are right my color is " + color_guessed);
}
```

Comment: else if ( colors.indexOf(color_guessed) === -1 ) alert("The color is is not in the list");

dosn't work with me .. i don't know why

Comment: Because one of the prevoius if's statement gets executed and the rest of if's are ommited. You shall remove "else" keyword: if ( colors.indexOf(color_guessed) === -1 ) alert("The color is is not in the list");

Comment: @tareq I've updated the answer to make it more clear what you shall do and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
colors.indexOf(color_choosed)
```

works fine on arrays but are case sensitive...
if you want to ignoreCase you should either care everything is lowerCase in your array and check for color_choosed.toLowerCase()

indexOf returns -1 if the element is not found in array

for performance and logic reasons you should check if its in array at first

Answer (score 0):

Thnx every body i've [solved] the code .. i used indexOf === -1

```
var colors=["blue","cyan","gold","grey","orange","red"];
var gussess = 0 ;
var color_choosed;
var color_guessed;
function game(){
        color_choosed = "grey";
        color_guessed = prompt("I'm thinking of one of these colors"); 
        if ( colors.indexOf(color_guessed) > colors.indexOf(color_choosed)) 
            alert("The color choosed is after my color");
        else if ( colors.indexOf(color_guessed) < colors.indexOf(color_choosed)&colors.indexOf(color_guessed) >0)
            alert("The coloris befor my color");
        else if ( colors.indexOf(color_guessed) == colors.indexOf(color_choosed))
            alert("congrats you are right my color is " + color_guessed);
        else if ( colors.indexOf(color_guessed) === -1 )
            alert("The color is is not in the list");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the `includes` function, that has been available since ES2016, is a much cleaner way of solving this, if you dont really care about giving the 'is after' or 'is before' prompts:

`if (colors.includes(color_guessed))`